# what kind of hell are waiting for liars or deceiver who mislead people

Tags: scripture, vedas

I'd like to know what kind of hell are waiting for liars or deceiver who mislead people to wrong path other than Dharma or liberation from material world?

Comment: Someone will give you the sanskrit version, this is completely in hindi. https://archive.org/details/garuda-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n465/mode/2up

Comment: Dear Proxy, thank you. I can't wait for it (^o^)